# Execute a remote process on a non-admin account using Powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-word, ms-office

I want to run aa remote process (winword.exe more specifically) from a remote machine using Powershell 2.0. One requirement is that the process is run by a non-admin user account. I'm able to run winword.exe if the user is part of the local administrator group on the remote machine, however when I remove it from the admin group, it fails - I get a winword.exe cannot be found error (32bit winword running on a 64bit 2008 server).

I've tried adjusting the PSSession configuration by granting the non-admin user account more elevated priveleges but it still fails:

```
Set-PSSessionConfiguration Microsoft.Powershell -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI
```

Is there something I'm missing here? Or does the user account explicitly require admin level priveleges on the server? Although PS tools would be a nice alternative, I would prefer using PS.

Comment: Did you give the user execute permission on the session configuration?

Comment: Will Your Winword windows be visible on the remote computer ? I was thinking we can't interact with the desktop of the remote machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to the "Understanding Session Configurations" paragrph in the [Administrator's guide to PowerShell Remoting](http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/7257.aspx) from PowerShell.com.